# How to increase and decrease a counter from one button - click and click again jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the code that I am currently using:

```
<script>
   $(".lk").click(function(){
   $(this).find("#lke").html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });
   });

   $(".lk").click(function(){
   $(this).find("#lke").html(function(i, val) { return val*1-1 });
   });
</script>
```

When the user clicks on the button, the value of #lke increases by 1. When he clicks again, the value decreases by 1. The code that I am currently using does not work so how would I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an external var to decide if you have to increment o decrement the value

```
<script>
   var increment = true;
   $(".lk").click(function(){
      var lke = $(this).find("#lke"), 
          value = parseInt(lke.html()) || 0;

      lke.html( increment ? value + 1 : value - 1);
      increment = !increment;
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because you assign two events for every click - one which increases the value and one which decreases it, so nothing happens.

You could use an external variable such as `toAdd` to determine which action to do:

```
var toAdd = 1;
$(".lk").click(function(){
    newValue = oldValue + toAdd;
    toAdd *= -1;
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(".lk").click(function() {
   if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
       $(this).removeClass('clicked'));
       $(this).find("#lke").html(function(i, val) { return val*1-1 });
   } else {
       $(this).addClass('clicked');
       $(this).find("#lke").html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });  
   }
});
```

You could also use a data attribute instead of checking for a class aswell.

Or use `toggleClass()`.

```
$(".lk").click(function() {
   if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
       $(this).toggleClass('clicked'));
       $(this).find("#lke").html(function(i, val) { return val*1-1 });
   } else {
       $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
       $(this).find("#lke").html(function(i, val) { return val*1+1 });  
   }
});
```

Comment: Using `toggleClass()` would be the same thing, so you don't have to use `removeClass()` or `addClass()`.

Answer (score 0):

You put two call of the same object, try this instead

```
<script>
   var val = 0; // Put the original value
   var negative = false;
   $( document ).ready(function() { // You need to declare document ready
      $(".lk").click(function(){
         val = val + ((negative) ? -1 : 1); // Change if its positive or negative
         negative = (negative) ? false : true;
         $("#lke").text(val); // Adjust the html ?
      });
   });
</script>
```